# Android compile will failed when a class or method reference in source file not exist, but will success when that is in aar file, how to fail this?

Tags: android, compilation, aar, nosuchmethoderror

Android compile will failed when a class or method reference in source file not exist;

But but will success when that is in aar file， how to fail compile when a class or method reference in aar file not exist?

If this compile success, it will crash when run time with a Exception such as "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError".

how to fail compile when a class or method reference in aar file not exist?

Comment: Post your error log or stack trace

Comment: there is no error log, just a common case. It means if I build an aar file A, without package some class what it depends, such as an other aar file B, and not declare it in pom file.
When i use this aar A, and not declare dependence of B in my project, it will success to build, But it will crash when running to code depends B.